# Can Pikachu Learn Volt Tackle?

Tags: pokemon-lets-go

In Pokemon let's go, can Pikachu learn Volt Tackle? Is the move in the game?

Comment: Is it your partner Pokemon from Let's Go Pikachu, or are you talking about any Pikachu that you catch?

Comment: Both cases your partner and ones you can catch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the looks of it, Pikachu cannot get Volt Tackle as a move. [Serebii](https://www.serebii.net/letsgopikachueevee/unavailableattacks.shtml) has a list of all the moves that are not available in Pokémon Let's Go, and Volt Tackle is within that list.